# JPA Specification like fails

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, specifications

I have the following code to do the search for the consedoc field, but I see that it does not search but rather tells me the number of records

```
public static Specification<Solicitud>likeConsedoc(String consedoc){
        if(consedoc.isEmpty() || consedoc.isBlank() || consedoc==null) { //carga todos los datos inicialmente sin filtrar
            System.out.println("Consedoc null or empty");
            return (root, query, criteriaBuilder)-> criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));
        }
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder)->
        criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(Solicitud_.CONSEDOC), "%"+consedoc+"%");
    }
```

In the logs I can see the query being executed and I can see the count clause which is not what I want.

```
select count(solicitud0_.id) as col_0_0_ from patrimonio.solicitud_usuario solicitud0_ where solicitud0_.consedoc like ?
```

I did the test with postman and it does not return any record
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FomMS.png)

Can someone help me, or suggest me to use to filter the data from my front end. I am using Angular and I am doing the pagination and filtering in the backend with Spring Boot

Truth is, I hadn't noticed that. With this I see that the backend is working fine. But in the frontend if I have a failure it does not show me the searched records it only shows me the total
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tygFj.png)

Comment: Did you maybe mean to tag this with Spring? Does this really have to do with your specification - When you execute this count query (the SQL itself against the database), what does it give you as the count value? Count is used for pagination within Spring, so it will execute multiple queries, and this would occur if your query returns no results. Maybe turn on parameter logging to see what is being sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Pagination starts with page 0. By passing in pageNumber=1, pageSize=15 you are telling Spring to skip the first 15 results - since there is only 1 result for this query, you get 0 results displayed. This information is contained in the returning results where it tells you there was 1 totalElements, 1 page in total, and there are no more records after this one.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post and added the error that I have in the frontend, it shows me the total in the table but not the record

Comment: I just found the error, in the frontend I was sending the page index increased by 1. I had been looking for the error for two days. Thank you very much for your help have a nice day